# You're the NSA, trying to decrypt a message between two friends

Tags: cipher, cryptography

You're a secret agent working for the NSA and you have monitored the messages between two friends for a while now. Suddenly, their messages become encrypted and you're on high alert. The first part of their message was sent twice (accidentally), an encrypted and decrypted version. This was the message:

```
The package has arrived, I am ready for pickup. When and where shall we meet?
```

Encrypted:

```
r.4NC"Hm,20QV}*;. `AI&*BU3;%);.-6/2NUF=eOt-+3Jq%2]TpH,MCJ5!F*}HT?jX,R>EqC''*H
```

Further analysis show the keyword was `password`. The next part of the message was sent encrypted, but with a different key. All you could find out about the keyword was that it is 4 letters long. The message was this:

```
pt3sLuD,91~1o&,:# D0bVs{O'Mov;vC%l3yFb
```

Time is running out and you fear it may be dangerous! Can you decrypt the message in time?

EDIT: I will post a hint later on today

**Hint 1:**

> C++ code (very basic) here for algorithm (won't spoil the answer!)
>  (This is my repo) https://github.com/Cube777/cube-lib/blob/master/src/cube-encrypter.cpp

**Hint 2:**
Another hint:

> The keyword is not an English word, but a sequence of 4 letters (not an abbreviation but a popular sequence of 4 letters)

Comment: Man, the NSA must be _really_ desperate to outsource their work here so often.

Comment: The number of characters is the same before and after encryption, so most likely we have to find a direct relationship between each character and its encrypted equivalent

Comment: Added the hint! :) Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, I sort of assumed that figuring out the encryption algorithm used was half the puzzle...

Comment: @JoeZ. Thats why its in spoiler tags ;) Use it only if you see fit!

Comment: Well, given that you decided to use Hungarian Notation for everything, the code is unreadable to me >_>

Comment: But it does work, I'll give you that.

Comment: Added another hint! Any progress on decryption? (should I add pseudo code for the algorithm?)

Comment: No, I've been trying to use repl.it. I didn't try my hardest yet, though.

Comment: I thought that I'd mention that the link is dead...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, so I used your code to create a brute-force generator to determine all possible decodings for all four-letter words. Since the input was a four-letter word, I assumed that it was also lowercase, and so the search space was only $26^4 = 456~976$, totally feasible for brute force.

Then, a quick search for an isolated "the" turned up all I needed: the key was `asdf` and the plaintext was `Coldplay makes the world's best music!`.

I can see why they'd want to hide that from the NSA. I mean, they're not Nickelback, but...

Comment: Haha shots we're fired... Have found any other way to decrypt the algorithm that doesn't use brute-forcing? I'm really interested to see if this works!

Comment: I was lazy, so a logical solution is probably not so doable.

Comment: This makes way for a part 2 :) Thanks though

Comment: There should be a movie about this answer. (Suggestion for the title: `The Immitation Game 2`).

Comment: there's one about the key. PIE FLAVOR!